# A fair die is rolled three times.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that

**a)** the second and third rolls are both larger than her first roll? [Ans:$P(A)=55/216$]

**b)** the result of her second roll is greater than that of her first roll and the result of her third roll is greater than the second? [Ans: $P(B)=20/216$]

I have the answers to these questions, but I'm more concerned about how to get to the answer or the idea behind it. All I know is that the sample space is $6^3 = 216$. Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part **(a)**, first consider the simple case where we roll two dice. What is the probability that the second roll is greater than the first?

Assuming a six-sided dice, the total number of outcomes $(i,j)$ is $6^2$. We need to count the outcomes in which the second roll is greater than the first; i.e. the number of pairs where $j > i$.

Any set of two distinct integers $\{a,b\}$ must have one smaller and one larger element; let us agree that the smaller number indicates the result of the first roll, and the larger number is the result of the second roll.

It follows that the number of such pairs is $6\choose2$, and our probability is $$\frac{6\choose2}{6^2}$$ Can you use this result to reason about three rolls? Or use independence of events?

A similar argument holds for part **(b)**. Any set of three distinct integers $\{a,b,c\}$ must have a smallest, middle, and largest element. Let the convention now be the smallest is roll 1, the middle is roll 2, and the largest is roll 3.

The total number of outcomes $(i,j,k)$ is $6^3$, and we have $6\choose3$ outcomes  for which $i<j<k$, so the result is $$\frac{6\choose3}{6^3} = \frac{20}{216}$$ Can you generalize this result to an increasing sequence of rolls of length $m$?

**Edit**: Further clarification for **(a)**

The set of outcomes $(i,j,k)$ for which $j > i$ and $k > i$ can be partitioned as follows (letting $i$ = roll 1, $j$ = roll 2, $k$ = roll 3):

roll 3 > roll 2 > roll 1

roll 2 > roll 3 > roll 1

(roll 2 = roll 3) > roll 1

We can simply count the number of events in each partition. We just argued from **(b)** that the number of outcomes where roll 3 > roll 2 > roll 1 is $20$. By symmetry, the number of outcomes where roll 2 > roll 3 > roll 1 is also $20$.

Finally, we need to count the outcomes where (roll 2 = roll 3) > roll 1. This is the same as the number of outcomes for which roll 2 > roll 1 in the 2-dice case (hence the hint), which we established is ${6\choose2} = 15$.

Tallying these up, we find the total is $20+20+15=55$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not seeing how $6\choose3$ would result in the answer for b. If it were combination, wouldn't it be random in "choosing" which number is rolled? So how is it certain that i<j<k? I have this similar concern for a, not sure how to obtain the probability for a with three rolls. -- To generalize b, though, would it be $C(6,m)$ / 6^m ?

Comment: The generalization is correct, although do you see why it works? The $C(6,3)$ comes from the fact that we need to count all the tuples where roll 3 > roll 2 > roll 1. One common way of counting is to establish bijections (if I tell you the number of noses in a room is 10, you know we have 10 people). Our bijection is between the set of size-3 subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and the set of outcomes $(i,j,k)$ for which $i<j<k$. Using the rule above $\{6,2,4\}$ _uniquely_ maps to $(2,4,6)$. There are $C(6,3)$ size-3 subsets of $\{1,\dots,6\}$, and each maps to an outcome of interest.

Comment: Please see edit for part **(a)**

Comment: Thanks, I see for part (a) that you can split the problem to three cases. It's a lot clearer now. I'm not keen at observing problems..

Comment: I don't see how doing C(6,3) automatically "arranges" the result to have what we want, i<j<k. Couldn't it be possible that the subset may be {6,2,1}? Does this necessarily mean {i,j,k} where i=6, j=2, and k=1? Or by what you mean of "uniquely maps", it is accounted for? Sorry if I'm being confused.

Comment: It is key to understand the difference between a __set__ and a __tuple__. In a set $\{a,b,c\}$, order of elements does not matter, and they cannot repeat. In a tuple $(i,j,k)$ the order matters and elements may be repeated. Each outcome of rolling 3 dice is a __tuple__, not a __set__. What we have defined is a function which takes a __set__ and returns a __tuple__ (i.e. an outcome). Nothing is automatically arranged, we have __defined__ the rule to arrange the elements of the set into a tuple. Since the mapping is unique, the number of size-3 subsets $C(6,3)$ = number of outcomes of interest.

Answer (score 2):

a) If the first die is a 6, then there is no way the other two can be larger. If the first is a 5, then there is only one way both the other dice can be larger (I.e. a 6 and a 6). If the first is a 4, then there are are 4 ways for the others to be larger -- ${(5,5),(5,6),(6,5),(6,6)}$. If it's a three, then we have 9 ways, ${(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)}$. Continuing this process will get you the answer -- $1+4+9+16+25=55$ possible ways.

b) Again, if the first roll is a 6, then no possible ways. If the first roll is a 5, again, no possibilities. If the first is a 4, then there's only one way -- $(5,6)$. If it's a three, then there are 3 ways, ${(4,5),(4,6),(5,6)}$. If it's a 2, there are 6 ways, ${(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,5),(4,6),(5,6)}$. If it's a one, there's 10 ways. This gives us $1+3+6+10=20$ ways.

Sorry if the answer is a bit crude, I'm on the phone :P hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. It did help, but it's more of a brute force way of achieving the answer. I'd like to know how to obtain the answer more "generally", if that makes sense. There's a comment about using combinations but it's still unclear to me

Answer (score 1):

Condition on the outcome of the first roll.  Let the outcomes of the three rolls be $X_1, X_2, X_3$, in that order. For simplicity of notation, consider the events $A = (X_2 > X_1)$, and $B = (X_3 > X_1)$.  Then by the law of total probability, $$\Pr[A \cap B] = \sum_{k=1}^6 \Pr[(A \cap B) \mid (X_1 = k)] \Pr[X_1 = k].$$  But observe that $A \mid (X_1 = k)$ and $B \mid (X_1 = k)$ are independent events, because $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent.  Furthermore, we easily see that $$\Pr[X_2 > k] = 1 - \Pr[X_2 \le k] = 1 - \frac{k}{6}.$$  Therefore, $$\Pr[(A \cap B) \mid (X_1 = k)] = \Pr[X_2 > k]\Pr[X_3 > k] = \Pr[X_2 > k]^2,$$ hence $$\Pr[A \cap B] = \sum_{k=1}^6 \Bigl(1 - \frac{k}{6}\Bigr)^2 \frac{1}{6} = \frac{55}{216}.$$

For the second part, an argument by counting is probably easiest, and was described in another answer.  The idea is to regard the outcomes of the three die rolls as an ordered triplet $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ where each $X_i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$.  The desired probability is simply the ratio of the number of desired outcomes divided by the total number of possible outcomes.  Of course, the latter is easy:  the total number of possible outcomes is simply $6^3 = 216$, since each outcome $X_i$ is independent of the others.  The numerator is slightly harder:  we observe that a desired outcome is one in which $1 \le X_1 < X_2 < X_3 \le 6$.  The key observation is to note that because the inequalities between the outcomes are *strict*, we cannot have any two die rolls equal in value.  Thus, if we count the number of ways to choose three distinct numbers from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, this uniquely corresponds to a desired outcome of the three die rolls.  So for example, $\{2, 5, 6\} \iff (X_1, X_2, X_3) = (2, 5, 6)$.  Since there are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ such ways to choose $3$ distinct numbers from $6$ distinct integers, we find that the desired probability is $$\Pr[X_1 < X_2 < X_3] = \frac{20}{216},$$ as claimed.

To do the above calculation using conditional probabilities is also possible, and requires a slight modification.  In particular, we must consider the probability $$\Pr[(X_3 > X_2 > X_1) \mid X_1 = k].$$  One way to compute this is to see that either $X_3 > X_2$, $X_3 = X_2$, or $X_3 < X_2$, given that both are greater than $X_1 = k$.  That is, $$\Pr[(X_3 > k) \cap (X_2 > k)] = \Pr[X_3 > X_2 > k] + \Pr[X_2 > X_3 > k] + \Pr[(X_3 = X_2) > k],$$ and we already know the LHS probability.  A simple symmetry argument shows that the first two terms on the RHS are equal, so all that remains is to find the last term.  But this is easy:  Since $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent, we have $$\Pr[(X_3 = X_2) > k] = \sum_{j = k+1}^6 \Pr[X_3 = j]\Pr[X_2 = j] = \sum_{j=k+1}^6 \frac{1}{6^2} = \frac{6-k}{36}.$$  Thus $$\Pr[X_3 > X_2 > k] = \frac{1}{2}\left(\Bigl(1 - \frac{k}{6}\Bigr)^2 - \frac{6-k}{36}\right) = \frac{(5-k)(6-k)}{72},$$ and we have $$\Pr[X_3 > X_2 > X_1] = \sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{(5-k)(6-k)}{72} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{54} = \frac{20}{216}.$$  As you can see, this is probably not the kind of solution you want to deal with on a first glance at the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider in 1st throw we got number 1
So in second throw we have to get higher number than 1,so there are 5 chances for getting higher number. 
Now consider in 2 Nd throw we got number 2
Now in third throw we have to get higher number than 2, so there are total 4 chances for getting higher number than 2
Hence probability is 
5*4/216 = 5/54

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).